# modRewrite custom redirect

Tags: mod-rewrite

How to rewrite if %{REQUEST_URI} begins with %{HTTP_HOST} ?

i.e. http://example.com/example.com_custom_text -> http://example.com/index.php?q=special&info=example.com_custom_text

Usage of %{HTTP_HOST} is important due to universality.

Does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^%{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=special&info=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have `%` variables in the expression (the 2nd part) of a `RewriteCond`. But you can use a `\1` to backreference the same match, and combine the URI and host, like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST};%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^|]+);/\1
```

So if a request is made for: `http://example.com/some_path`:

- `%{HTTP_HOST};%{REQUEST_URI}` = `example.com;some_path`
- `^([^|]+)` matches `example.com` and `\1`!=`some_path`

If a request is made for: `http://example.com/example.com_some_path`:

- `%{HTTP_HOST};%{REQUEST_URI}` = `example.com;example.com_some_path`
- `^([^|]+)` matches `example.com` and `\1` matches the beginning of `example.com_some_path`